# Libreoffice Calc is slowing down when working with big cells

Tags: 16.04, libreoffice

I'm experiencing Libreoffice Calc slowing down when working with large cells.

My file in libreoffice calc is a little bit worked out, with more than 10 spreadsheets, with formulas and automatic formatting. Not too complex, but with some details.

In one of the spreadsheets, I have large cells, almost 20, with more than 10 lines in each cell.

In this spreadsheet, libreoffice calc becomes too lazy. When I click one of this big cells, it takes almost 10 seconds to select it.

When I close and reopen it, it becomes fast again, but just for some time. After some use, it's slows down again.

I have the costume to suspend my computer with my spreadsheet opened. The problem can be related to suspend/awake process, but I don't have any evidence in this sense.

I have tried some solutions:

- Reinstalled libreoffice from Ubuntu Repository
- Checked my video card instalation (somebody said that could be lack of OpenGL support)
- Installed last version from ppa:libreoffice/ppa

None of those solved it.

My system details are:

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- Libreoffice Version: 5.1.6.2

Along with that, Libreoffice is crashing without giving any evidence of what cause it and without reporting the error.

Comment: How much RAM do you have? And how much does `top` or `htop` say libreoffice is using? (It may be `soffice.bin`)

Comment: I have 8GB and now it's using 2,1 GB, but it's working well right now. I'll check it when it starts slowing down.

Comment: 8GB of RAM should be plenty, but on the other hand 2.1GB being used by Libreoffice seems a lot to me. The slowdown could be caused by swapping, which is what I was thinking about. Run `vmstat 5` (where 5 indicates to update every 5 seconds) and keep an eye on the swap `si` and `so` columns. If they stay at 0 the problem isn't swapping, but if they increase when LO is being slow, that's the problem

Comment: @JoeP Now I could check it. It isn't using swap. Now it takes 863 MB and is presenting a slowdown.

Comment: Can you tell if it is CPU-bound? In `top` or `htop` does Libreoffice use all available CPU when in slowdown? Also what happens to the `Load:` value?

Comment: @JoeP I don't think so, usually it presents with very few processing load, but I'll check it next time it happens.

Comment: @JoeP Confirmed. All four cores are with less than 50% of activity.

Comment: So if it's not RAM or CPU, and assuming you have checked the Load Average, perhaps the next thing to check is the video driver. What is your video card and what driver are you using? Do you have a chance to test this spreadsheet on an Ubuntu system with different hardware?

Comment: I've listen to this possibility before. Someone said that it could be lack of OpenGL support. I updated by video driver with "Intel Graphics Update Tool for Linux* OS v2.0.2". I have a Intel® HD Graphics 520. After running glmark2, I received a score of almost 800. I supposed it was working well. About testing it in another computer, I'll check if I have some simple way to do it. (The spreadsheet doesn't lag immediately, but needs some continues use)

Comment: @JoeP I transferred back my work to Windows 10, with Libreoffice, and the spreadsheet is working perfectly fine. It's the same computer, which works with dual boot. To test it in another ubuntu computer is a little bit more complex, because I need to work with it for some days until it present the failure.

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't easy to test it in another ubuntu installation.  I could certify that the problem is related to suspend the system keeping the spreadsheet opened. I use this file as a support for my routine work. So I keep it opened all the time. If I keep it opened for days, passing through frequently system suspending process, it can't perform normally. To work with it, I need to close the spreadsheet every time I'm going to suspend the system.